# how to open the viewcontroller from the side menu(SWRevealviewcontroller) under the tab bar so that the tab bar should not be hidden at the bottom?

Tags: ios, swift4, tabbar

In my case I used the `SWRevealViewController` for the side menu and I have the tab bar at the bottom.

When I tried to open the other screen from the side menu then the tab bar has been hidden from the bottom. When I open this other screen from the side then the tab bar at the bottom should be visible.

I have tried to migrate to the other screen from the side menu.

These lines of code are written in the `didselect` method of the `tablview` in the class of the sidemenu:

```
if indexPath.row == 0
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gamelist", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 1
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "leaderboard", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 2
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "IGL_STORE", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 3
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "event", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 4
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "IGLNews", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 5
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "IGL_TV", sender: nil)
}
else if indexPath.row == 6//HOW TO PLAY
{
    // performSegue(withIdentifier: "IGL_Store", sender: nil)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

we need some code regarding how the SWRevealController was initialized, there's not enough information here for us to understand the cause of your issue.